# Empty space when I set height of a child element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a simple page with flex looks like this:

[image]

So this is what I try:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
  background-color: blue;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.main {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <nav class="inner sidenav">Sidenav</nav>
  <div class="inner main">Main</div>
</div>
```

My question is, when I set the height of the `.header`, there's a blank space between `.header` and the others. Anybody knows why? How can I fix it?

I know I can add more `div` to make it works, but I want a solution without adding any extra wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your content wrapped into two flex rows, and when height is distributed among those rows there are some extra space remained. All of that extra space is not given to last row automatically. So a gap remains unless you shrink the height of window to your contents' exact height.

If you want your second row to take remaining space using css, maybe you can assign remaining height to it with CSS like this:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
  background-color: blue;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}

.main {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

body
{
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <nav class="inner sidenav">Sidenav</nav>
  <div class="inner main">Main</div>
</div>
```